# Custom health actuator properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I'm working in java **springBoot** application **v 1.5.3**
i added **health actuator** and is working fine.
what i need to do is costomise status properties and put an other **properties name** like in the picture.
So i put for example globalStatus in place of status
Does any one have an idea how it should be done

thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
info:
    app:
        name: @project.name@
        version: @project.version@
    external-resources:
        services:
            '[service.util]': ${service.util.url}
            another_service: ${service.host}
        database:
            url: ${spring.datasource.url}
            username: ${spring.datasource.username}
    build:
        date: @timestamp@
        commit-sha: ${COMMIT_SHORT_SHA:xxx}
    deployment:
        date: ${DEPLOYMENT_TIME:xxx}
```

Just put all you need under `info` section of the `application.yml`

Comment: i already did that for the info actuator, but what i need is to customise health actuator wich serve for monitoring the application

Comment: @NasSim https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-actuators

Answer (score 0):

Custom properties can be added to the `/actuator/info` response by implementing `InfoContributor`

```
@Component
public class CustomInfoContributor implements InfoContributor {
@Override
  public void contribute(Info.Builder builder) {
    builder.withDetails(Map.of("custom-prop-1", "custom-value-1"));
  }
}
```

This will expose a new field and value in actuator/info response.
This structure can be a complex map of map as well.

for e.g.

```
@Component
    public class CustomInfoContributor implements InfoContributor {
    @Override
      public void contribute(Info.Builder builder) {
        builder.withDetails(Map.of("custom-props", Map.of("custom-prop-1","custom-val-1","custom-prop-2", "custom-val-2"));
      }
    }
```

This will expose additional structure as below

```
"custom-props": {
"custom-prop-1": "custom-val-1",
"custom-prop-2":"custom-val-2"
}
```